# Override "this"-keyword in GroovyShell

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to use GroovyShell in my java application for runtime execution of code. The code will be used for testing and will be exported to a java file when the program is finished. To make it easy for the users I would like the input to groovy to be as similar as possible to the java code that will be executed. This means that I, among other things, will remove types when the user tries to create a variable in order to avoid private variables ie.

```
    String str = "Lorem"
```

will be executed as

```
    str = "Lorem".
```

One thing that I can't seem to solve however is that, where a user would normally be able to just call a method `foo()` they now have to call the method on a object.

```
    Java code {
        foo();
    }

    Groovy code {
        im = new InteractiveMode();
        im.foo();
    }
```

This is of course because the method `foo()` is called on the object `this`, which in the groovy code references the script and not the java object. So my question is: Can I somehow override the `this` keyword in groovy or in some other way allow methods to be called on a object without having to specify what object every time?

**EDIT: To clarify**

This is what my code looks like now:

```
InteractiveMode test = new InteractiveMode();
GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell();
gs.setVariable("im", test);
gs.evaluate("im.foo();");
```

I want to get the same output with this instead:

```
InteractiveMode test = new InteractiveMode();
GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell();
gs.setVariable("im", test);
//Some groovy magic
gs.evaluate("foo();");
```

Comment: You could write it as a class, or try: `new InteractiveMode().with { foo() }`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean so I'll clarify in case there is some confusion. InteractiveMode is the class in which the GroovyShell is created. Foo, the method I need to call is declared in the InteractiveMode class. So if I were to replace the Groovy part (ie making it non-interactive) I would just write `this.foo();`. When using Groovy however I can't use `this.foo()` since `this` references the script and can't be overriden (or can it?) and have to therefore write `im.foo()`. 

Is this how you understood my question?

Comment: You mean like when you call setDelegate on the script?

Comment: Well, yes actually. That seems to be very close to what I'm looking for. However, I now can't seem to find out how to achieve this with Java code. This is what my code looks like now:

    `InteractiveMode test = new InteractiveMode();
    GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell();
    gs.setVariable("im", test);
    gs.evaluate("im.foo();");`

I would like the last line to be:

    `gs.evaluate("foo();");`

And still give exactly the same output.

Comment: See http://sysgears.com/articles/customizing-scripts-execution-in-groovyshell/

Comment: Why are you going to the trouble of removing their types?  It seems you could leave them alone and everything would still work, right?

Comment: The reason I'm removing the types is because the users will enter Java code, see what the output is, and when they're done they'll export their lines of code to a .java file. When a variable is declared with a type in Groovy it isn't added to the binding which means it won't be accessible for the next command. Removing the types were simply one way of adding the variables to the binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to pass in a customized CompilerConfiguration when you create your GroovyShell. Then you can set the script base class as described [in this post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/11/groovy-goodness-set-delegating-class.html).

You can also look into using a Binding if all you need is some properties accessible from the script. A Binding is just a map of property names to properties. If you want, you can even setup Bindings to a closure and then just call it like a method. Using Binding is described near the top of [this page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy)

If you don't want to to hold state outside of the script, then I'd use a Binding. If you need to hold state outside of the script, as in the car example, then the base class described in that post is what you want. The third option, if you need access to shared application state, would be to simply set the delegate on your script before it's run. This is shown near the bottom of the first link.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I'm unfortunately still a bit confused however. The mix between Groovy and Java makes me unsure how I should solve this. Most examples I find when researching this seems to be written in Groovy. My project however contains no Groovy at all except for the lines that the GroovyShell object evaluates (which are essentially just Java code). Because of this I have a hard time translating your links to my project.

Comment: Those examples don't use any of the magical groovyness. You should be able to just replace `def` with type declarations and add semicolons. If you use Intellij, it even has a groovy-to-java converter as part of the groovy plugin.